# Exception occurs while running both AXIS2 services and JAXWS services in the same application and same server

Tags: jax-ws, apache-axis, jboss5.x

To do a POC, I have a wrote a JAXWS class in the same package used for AXIS-2 services and configured that class in web.xml (content pasted below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <display-name>Apache-Axis2</display-name>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>PocServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.poc.PocJaxWS</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>PocServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/poc</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

After starting my server, i was able to generatel wsdl. But when i sent a sample request from soap-ui, i was getting many runTimeExceptions (exception log pasted below)

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory: org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPFactoryImpl
    at javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory.newInstance(SOAPFactory.java:65)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPFactoryImpl.createElement(SOAPFactoryImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.EnvelopeBuilderDOM.build(EnvelopeBuilderDOM.java:136)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.EnvelopeBuilderDOM.build(EnvelopeBuilderDOM.java:96)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:193)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:455)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:295)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:205)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:131)
    at org.jboss.wsf.common.servlet.AbstractEndpointServlet.service(AbstractEndpointServlet.java:85)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.hmco.ssms.common.hibernate.HibernateUtil.doFilter(HibernateUtil.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory: org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPFactoryImpl
    at javax.xml.soap.SAAJFactoryLoader.loadFactory(SAAJFactoryLoader.java:128)
    at javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory.newInstance(SOAPFactory.java:61)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPFactoryImpl.createElement(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)Ljavax/xml/soap/SOAPElement;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/axis2/saaj/SOAPFactoryImpl, and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at javax.xml.soap.SAAJFactoryLoader.loadFactory(SAAJFactoryLoader.java:123)
    ... 35 more
2012-03-14 17:01:23,358 ERROR [org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error processing web service request
org.jboss.ws.WSException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis2.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl
    at org.jboss.ws.WSException.rethrow(WSException.java:68)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:336)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:205)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:131)
    at org.jboss.wsf.common.servlet.AbstractEndpointServlet.service(AbstractEndpointServlet.java:85)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.hmco.ssms.common.hibernate.HibernateUtil.doFilter(HibernateUtil.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis2.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.createSOAPMessage(SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.java:288)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.toSOAPMessage(SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.java:256)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.exceptionToFaultMessage(SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.java:187)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.binding.SOAP11BindingJAXWS.createFaultMessageFromException(SOAP11BindingJAXWS.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAPBinding.bindFaultMessage(CommonSOAPBinding.java:671)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:496)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:295)
    ... 27 more
```

Please help me on this. Is this because of running both AXIS and JAXWS in the same app ? or is there any configuration to overcome this ??

Regards
Arun

Comment: Please help me out on this. Am waiting for someone to reply for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atlast found why :-)

- First of all both axis & JAXWS cannot run inside the same application
- Axis's SAAJ jar will load and will allow only its soap-factory to load and
  not jaxws's soap factory

So I took all the axis references in my project and removed `axis-saaj jar`. Now it started working :-)

Comment: I'm wondering if you'd have time to help me over the phone with this same thing?  :-)  If so, I can give you my number.  I know very little about JAX-WS and JBoss.

Comment: i can assist you through email. arun2381985@yahoo.com